# Is every bijective morphism an isomorphism in a small category?

Tags: category-theory, morphism

In any category, an isomorphism is an arrow $f \colon X \to Y$ together with an inverse arrow $f^{-1} \colon Y \to X$ such that $f \circ f^{-1} = 1_{Y}$ and $f^{-1} \circ f = 1_{X}$.

Now, clearly in some (algebraic) categories like $\mathsf{Group}$, $\mathsf{Set}$, etc. this definition is equivalent to the bijective morphisms. In others like $\mathsf{Pos}$, there are bijective morphisms between non-isomorphic posets.

But do we have equivalence in all small categories? Since any small category is isomorphic to one where the objects are sets and the arrows are functions.

Comment: Here is a small category: $\bullet\leftrightarrows\bullet$. What is a "bijective morphism" in this case? Also, $\mathsf{Set}$ is not small.

Comment: In $\mathsf{Top}$, the bijection between $[0,1)$ and $S^1$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes; thank you. Edited.

Comment: Did you really mean "small category"? Your description seems more apt for *concrete* category. "Small" just means that the collection of all objects and the collection of all arrows are sets.

Comment: I think small categories are meant. Small categories are concretizable. So we have a notion of a bijective morphism. Of course, the answer is still No. Just take any of the usual examples and consider the full subcategory on the two objects - this is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "bijective morphism" in a category. The notion of "bijective" only makes sense in a [concrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category), which is a category $C$ equipped with the additional data of a faithful functor $U : C \to \text{Set}$, and the meaning of "bijective" depends on the choice of $U$.

The failure of "bijective" morphisms to be isomorphisms has nothing to do with smallness, and any counterexample you've ever seen can be converted into a small counterexample by ignoring all objects other than the two objects involved in the counterexample.

In fact here is a minimal counterexample: take $C$ to be the category $\{ \bullet \to \bullet \}$ consisting of two objects and a morphism $f$ from one to the other, and take $U : C \to \text{Set}$ to be the functor sending both objects to the one-element set and $f$ to the unique function from this set to itself. Then $U(f)$ is a bijection but $f$ is not an isomorphism because there aren't any morphisms in the other direction at all. Here $C$ is not only small but finite.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, this mostly cleared my confusion up. The main problem that I had and still have ist whether an iso in a small category can be thought of as a bijective morphism. The answer I gathered is no - since there is no such thing as a bijective morphism in a category in general and so this concept is not of interest. It is though confusing since small categories are all equivalent to concrete ones where we have bijective morphisms. I guess this just means that bijective morphisms are categorically irrelevant.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I literally can't upvote anything because I'm new to this site - people posting comments without providing any insights nor understanding the circumstances are a miracle to me.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. Kind of a strange rule of MSE. I delete my stupid comment.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks, no worries.

Comment: @marxim: it's not that bijective morphisms are categorically irrelevant, it's that you can't even define "bijective" without choosing the extra data of a faithful functor to $\text{Set}$, and the meaning of "bijective" depends on this choice, so is not intrinsic. This is no different from how, say, the entries of a matrix depend on a choice of coordinates, and so are not intrinsic to a linear operator.

Comment: @Martin: probably the intent is to prevent people from making sockpuppet accounts to spam upvotes or downvotes. It's a reasonable feature but it would be nice if it were more obvious, I guess.